# Does coverage.py measure the function and class definitions?

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage

I am trying to achieve a 100% coverage for a basic python module.
I use Ned Batchelder's coverage.py module to test it.

```
1 class account(object):
2   def __init__(self, initial_balance=0):
3     self.balance = initial_balance
4   def add_one(self):
5    self.balance = self.balance + 1
```

These are the tests.

```
class TestAccount(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_create_edit_account(self):
    a = account1.account()
    a.add_one()
```

Here is what the coverage report I get.

```
    COVERAGE REPORT =
    Name                    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
   -----------------------------------------------------
   __init__                    1      1     0%   1
   account1                    5      3    40%   1-2, 4
   account2                    7      7     0%   1-7
```

As we can see, the lines 1-2 and 4 are not covered which are the defintions.
The rest of the lines are executed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your problem is described in the [FAQ](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/faq.html#faq):

> Q: Why do the bodies of functions (or classes) show as executed, but
>   the def lines do not?
>
> This happens because coverage is started after the functions are
>   defined. The definition lines are executed without coverage
>   measurement, then coverage is started, then the function is called.
>   This means the body is measured, but the definition of the function
>   itself is not.
>
> To fix this, start coverage earlier. If you use the command line to
>   run your program with coverage, then your entire program will be
>   monitored. If you are using the API, you need to call coverage.start()
>   before importing the modules that define your functions.

Answer (score 5):

Following jcollado's answer:

I have this problem with [Django nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) which only covers lines used by tests.

For fix it I launch firstly `manage.py` with coverage and after I launch tests.
`.coverage` file will contain both's reports.

My first command is [a custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/) which prints my project settings. Example:

```
coverage run ./manage.py settings && ./manage.py test myapp
```