# Error using py.test with coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, pytest, coverage.py

I'm using [`py.test`](http://pytest.org/latest/) with [`coverage`](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/). I was having problems with using `pytest-cov` with my tests; when I ran `py.test --cov=my_module --coverage-report=html .`, the function definitions in my module would be reported as missing, even though they should be executed when importing the module in the tests. This problem is mentioned in the [FAQ](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/faq.html).

Then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404716/) led me to try just running `coverage` rather than using `pytest-cov`, like so:

```
coverage run --source my_module py.test .
```

Now I'm getting this error (I've shown only the most recent calls in the traceback):

```
[long traceback]
File "[…]/python3.3/site-packages/py/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    sys.exit(pytest.main())
SystemExit: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

[long traceback]
File "[…]/python3.3/site-packages/coverage/collector.py", line 294, in stop
    assert self._collectors[-1] is self
AssertionError
```

Has anyone else run into this? How can I get `coverage` to work properly with `py.test`?