# nose2 coverage plugin timing

Tags: python, jenkins, code-coverage, nose2

I'm running nose2 tests with the coverage plugin. I noticed that decorators, class declarations, and function definitions aren't being marked as covered, even though the "actual code" underneath them is. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637093), which suggests starting coverage "earlier."

How would I do this via nose2? I tried exporting `NOSE_WITH_COVERAGE=True`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Additional context: eventually we're hoping to plug these tests into Jenkins, if that matters.

ETA: adding a `[coverage]` section with `always-on = True` to my `nose2.cfg` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The fool-proof way to get coverage started earlier is to use coverage to run nose, instead of using nose to run coverage.  For example, instead of:

```
$ nose2 blah blah blah
```

you can use:

```
$ coverage run -m nose2 blah blah blah
```

and then just leave out the nose coverage options from `blah blah blah`.

Comment: @swizzard: You'll have to show exactly the command line you used.  Your problem is a common one, and running nose inside coverage is the best solution. It will work for you.

Comment: `coverage run -m nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml --junit-xml` results in the non-test code being under-counted, essentially reversing what's counted as "covered".

Comment: @swizzard: I don't know why that would be. If you could send more details (including steps to reproduce) in an email, we can get to the bottom of it.